# What is the Expected number of happy nationalities

Tags: probability

Find the expected number of happy nationalities given that a nation is happy if all of its citizens are seating together. Given that 4 French, 4 Italians and 4 Germans are seating in a row in random order.
I known we would need to find the expected number by using indicators such that $$I_i = I(\text{number of }i\text{ happy nations})$$ and the answer would be in the formula of $$E(I_1 + I_2 + I_3) = 3\ * ( )$$I'm not sure what the probability of one of the indicators will be, if I had to put something, would it be $$\frac{4!*9!}{12!}$$ or am I looking at this all wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

The probability that at least one nationality is happy
$$\frac{{3\choose1}4!9!}{12!}\tag1$$
The probability that at least two nationalities are happy
$$\frac{{3\choose2}(4!)^26!}{12!}\tag2$$
The probability that three nationalities are happy
$$\frac{{3\choose3}(4!)^33!}{12!}\tag3$$
The probability that exactly one nationality is happy is given by $(1)-(2)+(3)$, the probability that exactly two nationalities are happy is given by $(2)-(3)$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you very much!